# How to avoid undefined in combineLatest?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two child components `<app-filter>` with:

```
 public filtersChanges = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

In parent component they are:

```
<app-filter></app-filter>
<app-filter></app-filter>
```

So, in parent component I get access to these components:

```
@ViewChildren(FilterComponent) filtersList: QueryList<FilterComponent>;
```

Then I listen changes `filtersChanges` from each components:

```
 this.filtersChanges = combineLatest(...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges)).subscribe((data) => {
            this.settings.filters = data;
        });
```

Problem is I want to assign `[]` to `this.settings.filters` if result from `combineLatest` is:

```
1. [undefined, undefined]
2. [null, null]
3. [[], []]
```

How to do that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you should be able to do this with a simple if statement inside your subscribe block. Like: "If data is one of the values you want to check for, then assign [] to this.settings.filters."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply replace falsy values with `[]` inside the `map`. Instead of

```
...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges)
```

have

```
...this.filtersList.map((f) => f.filtersChanges || [])
```